# What's the state of the art w.r.t research on the legal aspects of Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: legal

As AI gains capabilities, and becomes more prevalent in society, our legal system will encounter questions it has not encountered before.  For example, if a self-driving car is involved in an accident while being controlled by the AI, who is at fault?  The "driver" (who's really just a passenger), the programmer(s) who made the AI, or the AI itself?

So, what's on the cutting edge in terms of these kinds of issues at the intersection of law and artificial intelligence?

Comment: This question is interesting but a little bit too broad. Maybe you can formulate it so that more specific answers can be given. For example, in the answer below, you provide a link to a book, but when I first read this question I thought that you were looking for some document written by some government that enumerates the laws regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3):

One person working in this space is Dr. Woody Barfield. He just wrote a book titled *[Cyberhumans: Our Future With Machines](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319250489)* that focuses largely on the legal/policy issues around AI (and related topics). In addition to the book, he is continuing with other research in this area.